# How to count the number of rows after applying a condition another column, while grouping?

Tags: python, group-by, counting, cumsum

```
df1 = [[aa, '21/01/2022', ''], [aa, '22/01/2022', '22/01/2022'],
       [aa, '22/01/2022', ''], [aa, '22/01/2022', ''],
       [bb, '25/01/2022', '25/01/2022'],[bb, '26/01/2022', ''], 
       [bb, '26/01/2022', ''],[cc, '21/01/2022', ''], 
       [cc, '21/01/2022', '22/01/2022'], [cc, '21/01/2022', '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns =['userid', 'Created', 'Signed_up'])
```

I have the above dataframe, and what I'm looking to do is count the number of plans 'Created' after previously having 'Signed up' with another Plan.
Meaning, each row in the dataframe is a Plan generated by a user, and I want to count the number of plans that each user generated after having previously having signed up, taking into account that each user can have on signed up plans ,which simplifies the task a bit.

My assumption would be to use the combination of groupby() and cumsum() or cumcount(), but what I am having trouble with is incorporating the condition of having a previously notna() 'Signed_up' column.

Desired Output:

```
df2 = [[aa, '21/01/2022', '', ''], [aa, '22/01/2022', '22/01/2022', ''],
       [aa, '22/01/2022', '', '1'], [aa, '22/01/2022', '', '2'],
       [bb, '25/01/2022', '25/01/2022', ''],[bb, '26/01/2022', '', '1'], 
       [bb, '26/01/2022', '', '2'],[cc, '21/01/2022', '', ''], 
       [cc, '21/01/2022', '22/01/2022', ''], [cc, '21/01/2022', '', '1']]
    
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns =['userid', 'Created', 'Signed_up', 'count'])
```

Any help and suggestions are appreciated! Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(r'', np.NaN)
df['CouNT'] = df.groupby(df.groupby(['userid'])['Signed_up'].ffill()+df['userid']).cumcount()
```

Updated code:

Here, you can handle the group of NaN, by fill with unique value or index value, However I have fill with `empty` string and later concate with `userid`, which also helped to bring your desire output.

```
df.groupby((df.groupby(['userid'])['Signed_up'].ffill()).fillna('')+df['userid']).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
    userid  Created     Signed_up   cnt
0   aa     21/01/2022   NaN         0
1   aa     22/01/2022   22/01/2022  0
2   aa     22/01/2022   NaN         1
3   aa     22/01/2022   NaN         2
4   bb     25/01/2022   25/01/2022  0
5   bb     26/01/2022   NaN         1
6   bb     26/01/2022   NaN         2
7   cc     21/01/2022   NaN         0
8   cc     21/01/2022   22/01/2022  0
9   cc     21/01/2022   NaN         1
```

Comment: Thanks for the above answer!
This actually makes a lot of sense, there is one unintended output though in the logic, what is actually happening, the second (outer) group by is also grouping on the np.NaN (rows that haven't been filled with the ffill()) and the cumcount is cumulative counting the blanks as well, which is not required.

Comment: Hi if it helpful please accept solution as an answer.